# Deleting SVN Connection on cloned machine

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have cloned a development machine dev-1 for extended testing purpose. Dev-1 has svn folters. I want to cut the connection of these folders on dev-2. How can I do that without damaging the SVN connection between dev-1 and the repository?

Comment: You should use the `export` command to create a non-versioned "snapshot" of the desired revision. An exported copy has no connection to the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Subversion server does not track what is checked out in any way (with the exception of locks being tied to a specific working copy) so there is no "connection" to worry about "damaging."

You can make dev-2 lose any information about where its files came from in two ways:

1. Delete the `.svn` directory from the root of the working copy on dev-2
2. Delete the working copy on dev-2 and perform an `svn export` of the content from the appropriate repository URL.